# Function that is Differentiable Everywhere but not of Bounded Variation

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question, lebesgue-integral

Folland contains the following exercise:

> Let $F(x) = x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ and $G(x) = x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x^2})$ for $x \neq 0$ and $F(0) = 0 = G(0)$. Show that $F$ and $G$ are differentiable everywhere but $F \in BV([-1,1])$ and $G \notin BV([-1,1])$

(BV is the set of functions of bounded variation)

I'm confused about the point Folland is trying to make with this example. Is he trying to say $F$ and $G$ are differentiable everywhere but $G$ cannot be attained by integrating a function? Doesn't that contradict the fact that I just took derivatives of $G$? I think I'm confusing an important detail, but can't figure out what.

Comment: what is the index of the exercise?

Comment: index? I'm guessing what you mean here: its Chap 3 number 33.

Comment: He doesn't "try to make a point". It's just an analysis exercise, and fun to solve.

Comment: I think the idea is that $G$ has more wiggles near the origin and the increasing/decreasing parts add up to $\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no contradiction.

Both $F$ and $G$ are everywhere differentiable, hence each can be obtained by integrating their respective derivatives, but that doesn't imply that they are of bounded variation.

Presumably, that's the point of the exercise.

On a given interval, say $[-1,1]$, an everywhere differentiable function *might* be of bounded variation (e.g., $F$), or it might *not* be of bounded variation (e.g., $G$).